# Error in importing RangeParameter from ax in python

Tags: python, optimization

Getting the following error when trying to import RangeParameter from ax
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bounds'

Comment: could u provide us with a code snippet to help you identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `scipy` to version **1.1** or above.